# как в devtools соохранить локальные изменения css?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

1. Есть сайт размещенный на хостинге
2. Ножно внести изменения в css, чтобы при обновлении стр изменения не сбрасывались
3. При этом изменения нужны только локально, сделать нужно без доступа к самому сайту

есть такой вариант?

Comment: [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) ?

Comment: mb, i need some time to check this )

Comment: то что доктор прописал, напишешь ответом, укажу решением! от души...